# What is the JPA method name for the query?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I would like to know what the JPA method would be for the corresponding query.

```
SELECT * FROM topic WHERE is_deleted = false AND skill_id = :skillId ORDER BY display_order ASC
```

Comment: I am not sure on how to add the skillId.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "JPA method"? What have you tried so far? Do you have any (Java) code to share that illustrates your problem in more detail?

Comment: I am looking for method like `findAllBySkillIdIsDeletedFalseOrderByDisplayOrderAsc`.

Comment: Any pointers on how to write this type of methods would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters to your derived query are simply arguments to the derived query method. So you'll want your Repository to look something like this:

```
interface TopicRepository extends JpaRepository<Topic, Integer> {
    public List<Topic> findAllBySkillIdAndIsDeletedFalseOrderByDisplayOrderAsc(String skillId);
}
```

This is assuming that Topic has an ID of type Integer, and that skillID is of type String.